# Google Sheets SQL Query - Cell reference returns record

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to run a relatively (for me!) complex query in google sheets, it has a few different parts to it but doesn't work.  After much playing around I've found it's down to one small part of it that doesn't return the expected results.

If I run this...

```
=query('Link: AdNo | ClassPeriodID'!A2:D59001,"SELECT D WHERE C = 'AMon:1'",1)
```

it returns the exact response I want - a list of all classes (content of column D) that match AMon:1 (in column C).

However, if I make a cell B1 =AMon:1 and run this...

```
=query('Link: AdNo | ClassPeriodID'!A2:D59001,"SELECT D WHERE C = '"&B1&"'",1)
```

it only returns the first entry in that list.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's difficult to ascertain the cause of such a problem when we don't have access to the spreadsheet. Could you make a copy and share a link to it (deleting student names or other sensitive data if you like, since those don't seem they'd affect the QUERY)? That would be the most efficient and effective way for the volunteer contributors here to assess and offer feedback or a solution.

Answer (score 0):

make sure B1 is the right cell

```
=QUERY('Link: AdNo | ClassPeriodID'!A2:D, "select D where C = '"&B1&"'", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help all, I think it was just one of those weird bugs, I deleted the original and copy/pasted the above back in (I'd copied it out originally) and it worked.